# How to administer the Azure Durable functions Task Hub locally?

Tags: c#, azure, orchestration, azure-durable-functions

I am currently developing an Azure Durable Function and I ran into the issue that unfinished orchestrations would hang around for next time after I tried to run my functions.

The problem was the task hub, as explained in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438156/azure-durable-function-orchestration-spawns-many-unwanted-activities):

> Orchestrations were created and did not finish in a previous run. Orchestrations are durable and long-running, so they will continue to try to run until they complete or fail, even after you shut down your function app and restart it.

The problem now is that while there is information on how I'd manage the task hub on Azure, I cannot then find any information on how to administer it while I am doing local testing.

Right now, I change the name of the test hub every time the problem arises, but I would much rather have a few lines of code that simply clear any existing data in the task hub.

How do I administer the Azure Durable functions Task Hub locally, in code?

Comment: You can go in and delete the Task hub from the storage and tables. I am sure this is scriptable.  However it is just easier to keep changing the hub name and then blowing it all away once a month or so.

Comment: It should definitely be scriptable, if it was running on Azure. I can not find the Task hub or its parts locally.

Comment: Use Azure storage explorer and use add account to attach to a local emulator. The defaults should all be fine unless you have customised your config. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the Azure Storage Emulator to clear out your local instances of the TaskHub. You can actually use the command `AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all` if you don't have any other data stored in your local emulated storage that you care about. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329345/how-to-clear-azure-storage-emulator-data-from-command-line), you can find that exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator`.

If you do have blobs, tables, or queues that are being emulated locally that you don't want to wipe just to remove the reference to the TaskHub, you can do as Murray Foxcroft suggested in the comments and use the storage explorer to connect to your local emulator, and remove all references to your specific TaskHub. The TaskHub uses a combination of tables, blobs, and queues, so make sure to be thorough.

Comment: Yes, Murray's comment was very helpful, but it still means I have to manually change/Delete something between test runs. I really need something I can put into my code so I do not need to worry about manual administration

Comment: As mentioned above, if you don't have any dependencies on blobs, tables, or queues in your local emulator beyond what Durable Functions relies on, you can use the command `AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all`. This could very easily be included as the first step in a startup script that both clears out the emulator and starts up your function application.

Answer (score 1):

[Durable Functions Monitor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor) VsCode extension shows all your Task Hubs and allows to administer, cleanup and even remove them.